# Memory performance in AWS

Tags: memory, amazon-web-services, benchmarking

I am doing some benchmarking of memory performance on m3.xlarge and it seems very slow.  I am getting about 2.1545Gb/sec for reads and 1.126Gb/sec writes.  I get 2x that on my laptop.  Is this normal performance?

Comment: Which benchmark are you using? Are you using HVM AMI?

Comment: Using sysbench.  I am using Ubuntu (aki-88aa75e1)

Comment: You should also add in your post the parameters used in sysbench exection.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what laptop you're running your benchmark on, but you should factor in that anything running on AWS is running in a virtualised (XEN) environment, which is usually going to be slower than the same specs on a physical machine. If performance on AWS is what you're looking for, it might be worth checking out instances like c3.8xlarge or cc2.8xlarge which will should get you as close to bare-metal as possible.

Depending on your business case, you should look at distributing you computing loads on a large number of smaller instances, number that could be scaled according to your own needs.

I hope this helps a little, let me know how I can improve the answer :)

Comment: I am more wondering about benchmarks and performance that other people have seen.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, make sure you are not swapping (Memory to disk) at all

```
swapoff -a
```

you can check your swappiness here
[turn-swap-off-permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103242/is-it-safe-to-turn-swap-off-permanently)

Hope it helps

Comment: swappiness is at 10.  I will give that a try thought.  I am still wondering if those number are normal.

Comment: Don't be surprise that the EC Instance is slower than your own physical hardware. Virtualization takes it toll due to page sharing and other techniques. Virtual machines can be overcommitted on memory and still not swap. However, if the over-commitment is large, performance in the virtual machines is significantly reduced. But since VM are the mainstream, we only can try to tune them.